# What happens if UI makes a rest call and the server stops?

Tags: spring, rest, api, single-page-application

Suppose, UI is making calls to rest service and the server stops.

- Does UI come to know about the server's state?
- Does UI get any response back from the server?
- What difference does it make if the rest call was POST or PUT?

Comment: How about trying it? What happens when you don't start any web server on your machine and type `http://localhost` in your browser address bar? What happens when you do the same using an AJAX request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When REST Api is stopped,the UI/Browser/Client will show "Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to " error, irrespective of request type: PUT /POST.

To answer your questions :

**Does UI come to know about the server's state?**
If Server stops, you will get an error like : error connecting server. Which can be traced to multiple rootcauses. One of them can be : Server has stopped.

In case of error, Server's state can be sent to client using various error codes like:
**500 Internal Server Error** The 500 status code, or Internal Server Error, means that server cannot process the request for an unknown reason. Here is list of status codes for REST APis: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html

**Does UI get any response back from the server?**
If server is stopped, UI/Client will receive no response.

**What difference does it make if the rest call was POST or PUT?**
If the server has stopped, it doesn't make any difference.

You can run this scenario using a browser and running any app/REST service in your local machine.
(For this test you need not have any REST application running in your local, as you only want to test when it is stopped)

For instance, if your REST application server is up and available at port 8080, you can send request to this server by sending request form your browser : http://localhost:8080

For testing with POST/PUT collections, you can use any API Development tools like : Postman.

Let's assue your REST Api , exposes following urls :

/myPostRequest POST
/myPutRequest PUT

When you hit these urls from POSTMAN you get the same response :

POST http://localhost:8080/myPostRequest :

Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:8080/transition-order.

PUT http://localhost:8080/myPutRequest :

Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://localhost:8080/transition-order.

Answer (score 1):

Client(could be UI) and Server are two dumb applications. They do and say what they are told to.

So whenever a client tries to call a server on a socket and there is no server listening to it, there is no response returned to the client. The client can interpret it in whatever way it wants. Most of the browsers show `<host> refused to connect.`

But if a server is listening to a socket, it responds to the client whichever way it was programmed to do. The server sends an appropriate status code and expects that the client knows how to interpret it. A server can send any random number it wants... the catch is, the client must know how to interpret it. otherwise, it's just one-way communication.

In order to provide smooth client-server communication, section 10 of RFC 2616 defines various codes with specific meaning as shown here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

These status codes are the same for all the types of Http methods.